# PC-Lint with Azure Pipelines - Has anyone ever tried to configure PC-Lint with azure pipelines?

Tags: azure-pipelines, pc-lint

I have CCS and Visual studio projects build on azure pipelines. The CCS projects build from the command line using eclipse. I have tried PC-Lint on CCS but because of licensing and in an attempt to reduce the number of licenses needed to use PC-Lint I want to try and configure it on my pipelines. Then, only 1 license is needed.

Has anyone tried this?

I have not yet tried anything. Just fishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, there is no PC-Lint plugin or task that can be integrated into Azure DevOps. For PC-Lint integration issues, I think you can contact [PC-Lint Support](https://pclintplus.com/support/) to further confirm whether them support integration into Azure DevOps.

There are some other extensions with similar functions that you can use in Azure DevOps, such as [Puma Scan Professional Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PumaSecurity.PumaScanProfessional-AzureDevOps) and [Kiuwan TFS Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kiuwan-publisher.kiuwan-analysis-extension).